# Woocommerce Single Product Page Button For Specific Categories Only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I have added code to display a "View Product Sample" button on the woocommerce page.  The button functions correctly; however I would like for the button to display only for a certain category.  The category that we have is "e-courses"

Here is the code I have used for the button:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','custom_button_by_categories');
function custom_button_by_categories() {

 global $post;

$demoslug = $post->post_name;

$demourl = get_bloginfo('url').'/courses/'.$demoslug.'/';

    $demotitle = esc_attr($post->post_title);

echo '<a href="'.$demourl.'" target="_blank" button type="submit" class="button sample">View Product Sample</a>';
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `has_term()` Wordpress function (where you will have to define your product category).

You can use **`woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart`** with a priority above 30 this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', function(){
    global $product, $post;

    // Set HERE your product category (ID, name or slug)
    if ( has_term( 'e-courses', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){

        $demourl = get_bloginfo('url').'/courses/'.esc_attr($post->post_name).'/';

        $demotitle = esc_attr($post->post_title);

        echo '<a href="'.$demourl.'" target="_blank" button type="submit" class="button sample">View Product Sample</a>';
    }
}, 31 );
```

Or also using your hook:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button','custom_button_by_categories');
function custom_button_by_categories() {

    // Set HERE your product category (ID, name or slug)
    if ( has_term( 'e-courses', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){

        global $post;

        $demoslug = $post->post_name;

        $demourl = get_bloginfo('url').'/courses/'.$demoslug.'/';

        $demotitle = esc_attr($post->post_title);

        echo '<a href="'.$demourl.'" target="_blank" class="button sample">View Product Sample</a>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works.

Comment: Loic  Thank you for your help.  The code you suggested worked beautifully.